Removing options to change the interpretation of a question on exponential RV's

The lifetime of two brands of bulbs $X$ and $Y$ are exponentially
distributed with the mean life of $100$ hours. Bulb $X$ is switched on
$15$ hours after Bulb $Y$ has been switched on. The probability that
bulb $X$ fails before Bulb $Y$ is? The options are: $(A).
> \frac{15}{100} (B). \frac{1}{2} (C).\frac{85}{100} (D). 0$ (See Linked Question)

As mentioned in the answers, the options only make sense if Y survives the first 15 hours.
However, if the options were not given, then would the following solution be correct?
$$P(Y<15)=F_Y(15)= 1-e^{-\lambda x}=1-e^{0.01x}\approx0.1392$$
P(Y fails before X)
$$=P(Y<15) + P(Y>15)P(Y fails before X)$$
P(Y fails before X) = 1/2 by memoryless property if it survives to 15:
$$=0.1392+(0.8607)(0.5)=0.56955$$
The probability we want is the complement of Y fails before X:
$$=1-0.56955=0.43045$$
If you apply the difference of two exponential random variables, then also you get the same answer.

Yes - that is what one of the answers to the linked question is saying with $\frac12 P(Y \geq 15)$
